# How to use addTranslation() on an entity's multi-value paragraph?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm trying to programmatically update a multivalue paragraph field and add a translation. In the code below **field_product_description** is the paragraph's field that I'm updating and **field_images_descriptions** is the node's field that references the paragraph. The code only updates the first iteration ([0]) of the paragraph. How can I also update the other paragraph values?

```
<?php
                  $lang_node->field_images_descriptions->entity
              ->addTranslation($lang_code, [
                  // field_product_description is a multi-value field
                  // how can I update it's other values
                  'field_product_description' => $desc1,
              ])->save();
    ?>
```

SOLVED: Working code:

```
<?php

foreach ($lang_node->field_images_descriptions as $delta => $item) {

          $item->entity->addTranslation($lang_code, [
              'field_product_description' => $desc1[$delta],
          ])->save();
        }

        $lang_node->save();
```

Comment: `field_images_descriptions` should be the multi-value field according to the field name.

Comment: Yep, it is a multi-value field. So, if $desc1 is an array with the multi-values, how can I populate field_product_description's multi-values with it in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over the multi-value field:

```
foreach ($lang_node->field_images_descriptions as $delta => $item) {
  $item->entity->addTranslation($lang_code, [
    'field_product_description' => $desc[$delta],
  ]);
}

$lang_node->save();
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it working with a slight modification - added to the original post.